# weatherData is not printing in my command line

Tags: node.js, api, express, command-line-interface, node-modules

[Weather Data not printing in my command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC13f.png)

I tried to print the weatherData as shown in the image from the URL, but it's not printing out in the console. What could the problem and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code (besides that it comes as a screenshot):

- Lines 11 and 14 refer to different `response` objects.
- The `data` event delivers only one chunk of data; there may be several, followed by an `end` event.

```js
https.get(url, function(response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  var weatherData = "";
  response.on("data", function(data) {
    weatherData += data.toString();
  }).on("end", function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(weatherData));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to download is use Windows native `Curl` command which you can run via a Cmd console window, to save the response file, then query that response.txt

First confirm your url is valid (click link below)

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Paris&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe&unit=metric

If you are using windows 10 or 11 you should have a native version of curl simply try this at cmd line (**NOTE** you need for each `&` within the url to escape with `^` like this `^&`) or use "URL" (so full double "quotes") but beware when nesting in shell commands.

```
curl -o response.txt https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Paris^&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe^&unit=metric

type response.txt
```

you could include both in one line but for the `&type` that last & does not need ^escape

```
curl -o response.txt https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Paris^&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe^&unit=metric&type response.txt
```

after the download you should see the response.txt in the console.

so you can call that command any way you wish (hidden>nul or not) and or read the text file on the screen or in any application you choose.

Response.txt

> {"coord":{"lon":2.3488,"lat":48.8534},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":277.1,"feels_like":277.1,"temp_min":275.8,"temp_max":278.23,"pressure":1009,"humidity":98},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.03,"deg":0},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1641768056,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2012208,"country":"FR","sunrise":1641714129,"sunset":1641744764},"timezone":3600,"id":2988507,"name":"Paris","cod":200}