# Weather Data in express and node.js not printing in my command line

Tags: node.js, express, https, command-line, response

```
const { response } = require("response");
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https")
const app = express ();

app.get("/", function(req,res) {
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&applied=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe&unit=metric";
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
  })

  response.on("data", function(data) {
    const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(weatherData);
  })

  res.send("Welcome to the future");
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
})
```

The problem here is that when I type
response.on to get data from the url
to print it in the command line, it
brings **const { response } = require
("express")** as shown above which is
very alien to me.
Please, how do I fix it so I can get
my weatherData printed in the CMD?

Comment: You're missing a quote `"` at `require("express)` on line 2

Comment: It was a typo. I have it there already

Comment: So how do I still fix it.

Comment: @jfriend. Can you point out the multiple syntax error. Cos the one missed out was the quote

Comment: Also also have a `\`` character at the end of your `console.log("listening on port 3000")\`;` line

Comment: I was thinking maybe the const { response } above is the one hindering from printing the weatherData in the console. What you think? Cos am just seeing it for the first time there

Comment: Your URL is wrong. You have a query parameter named "applied", but it should be "appid"

Comment: A lot of issues in your code. remove `const { response } = require("response");`, move `response.on("data",` to right after `console.log(response.statusCode);`  , `const req = https.get(url` , then `req.end()`...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623525/weatherdata-is-not-printing-in-my-command-line?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things you'll need to change.

First, this section is wrong:

```js
https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
})
response.on("data", function(data) {
    const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(weatherData);
})
```

Since "response" is a parameter you receive from the callback on the "get" function, you need to declare the "response.on" inside the funcion scope, like this:

```js
https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data) {
        const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(weatherData);
    })
})
```

Also, the "data" event only delivers a chunk of data. You should be listening for an "end" event aswell, and only parse the data when you receive the "end" event

```js
https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    const result = []
    response.on("data", function(data) {
        result.push(data);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        const weatherData = JSON.parse(result.join(""));
        console.log(weatherData);
    })
})
```

And since you're not using the module named "response", you also need to remove this:

```js
const { response } = require("response");
```

And then correct all the typos that were already mentioned in the comments, which were:

1. Add the missing quote " at require("express) on line 2
2. Remove the extra backsting at console.log("listening on port 3000")`; on line 17
3. Change the second query parameter on your URL on line 6 from "applied" to "appid"

Comment: And, you can't assume that one `data` event contains the entire data.  Whether that's true or not depends upon the amount of data and network conditions.  Accumulate all data and then process it all in the `end` event.  Personally, I never use plain `https.get()` any more as there's too much boiler plate code to write to use it safely  and handle errors.  I'd rather use a higher level library such as `got()` that is promise-based.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct. I edited my answer to include the "end" event listener.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm your url is valid

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe&unit=metric

If you are using windows 10 or 11 you don't need all those responses simply try this at cmd line (**NOTE** you need for each `&` within the url to escape with `^` like this `^&`)

```
curl -o current.txt https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London^&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe^&unit=metric

type current.txt
```

you could include both in one line but for the &type that last & does not need ^escape

```
curl -o current.txt https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London^&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe^&unit=metric&type current.txt
```

after the download you should see the response in the console.

so you can call that command any way you wish (hidden or not) and or read the text file on the screen or in any application you choose.

Current.txt

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":276.78,"feels_like":272.23,"temp_min":275.76,"temp_max":278.14,"pressure":999,"humidity":84},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.17,"deg":250},"clouds":{"all":9},"dt":1641696366,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2019646,"country":"GB","sunrise":1641715415,"sunset":1641744666},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple version using the `got()` library for making the http request.  It's a promise-based, higher level library that is just a lot easier to use than the `https` library which works at a lower level and requires more code to work properly and handle errors.

Here's how you would do this with the `got()` library:

```
const got = require("got");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=536bcef96b2f01cd9b9f076db90807fe&unit=metric";
        const result = await got(url).json();
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

Changes:

1. Fixed URL (change `applied` to `appid`).
2. Switch to `got()` library for the http request and built in JSON parsing
3. Add error handling
4. Send result as JSON

This generates the following output:

```
{
  coord: { lon: -0.1257, lat: 51.5085 },
  weather: [ { id: 800, main: 'Clear', description: 'clear sky', icon: '01n' } ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: {
    temp: 276,
    feels_like: 271.47,
    temp_min: 274.33,
    temp_max: 277.49,
    pressure: 1000,
    humidity: 86
  },
  visibility: 10000,
  wind: { speed: 5.66, deg: 250 },
  clouds: { all: 8 },
  dt: 1641707384,
  sys: {
    type: 2,
    id: 2019646,
    country: 'GB',
    sunrise: 1641715415,
    sunset: 1641744666
  },
  timezone: 0,
  id: 2643743,
  name: 'London',
  cod: 200
}
```