# Node : Put request is not updating the request data on the browser but updates on Command Line, Weather API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a beginner in Node, as I try to update the API request(Weather API) in the browser it never changes but if I try to run on command line it forecast the live weather.

```
const express = require("express");
const { all } = require("express/lib/application");
// HTTPS library requrired`
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get("/", function(req, res){

    // Getting data from external server
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Mumbai&appid=---------------------------------&units=metric";

    // Adding functions to our own server
    https.get(url, function(respone){
        console.log(respone.statusCode);

        // Getting data and putting on our server
        respone.on("data", function(data){

            // Parsing the data to an actuall javascript object
            var allData = JSON.parse(data)
            const temp = allData.main.temp;
            const description = allData.weather[0].description;
            const icon = allData.weather[0].icon;
            const imageUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon +"@2x.png"
            res.write("<p>The weather type here is: "+description+"</p>")
            res.write("<h1>The temperature here is: "+temp+"</h1>")
            res.write("<img src = "+imageUrl+"></img>");
            res.send();
            console.log(allData)
        })
    })
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})
```

[Command Line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkHDZ.jpg)
[Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5di3s.jpg)

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? There is no PUT request that you are showing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70623889/16462950.

Comment: Apologies its the GET request, all I want is to get the live weather forecast data but it's not updating on the chrome browser but when I try to run it on the command line it broadcast the live weather data.

Comment: I found the issue it was with my Browser, now it's resolved.