# data fatching form api to html in node

Tags: node.js, arrays, api, request

I was learn create wather app by using node.js form youtube and i just copy the code that he was writing but there code is work properly and my code dose not work

in my code I don't understand this line and after type this line my code is give arror before this every thing is right

```
 const rtd = adata.map((val) => replaceVal(index, val)).join(" ");
        res.write(rtd);
```

the code in this image is written by me and this code is note work

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
var requests = require('requests');
const replaceVal = (tempval, orgVal) => {
let temperature = tempval.replace('{% tempval %}', orgVal.current.temp_c);
 temperature = temperature.replace('{% location %}', orgVal.location.region);
 temperature = temperature.replace('{% country %}', orgVal.location.country);
return temperature;
}

const index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
if (req.url == '/') {
    requests('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=fbffa2e936464bd292b70117221308&q=india&aqi=no')
    .on('data',  (chunk) => {
        const jdata = JSON.parse(chunk);
        const adata = [jdata];
        // console.log(adata)
        // console.log(adata[0].current.temp_c)
        const rtd = adata.map((val) => replaceVal(index, val)).join(" ");
        res.write(rtd);
    })
    .on('end', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log('connection closed due to errors', err);
        
        res.end();
            // console.log('')
        });
    }
})

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");
```

this is screen shot of the video

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add your code to this post directly, not as an image (we can't/won't help you if we need to retype all your stuff manually)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70623889/16462950